# Сортировка массивов перечислений в Java

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, коллекции, enum

Имеется некое перечисление

```java
enum MyEnum {
    FOO, BAR, BAZ, QUX, ARG, ANT;
}
```

И массив/список из его значений (длиной больше чем "длина" перечисления `MyEnum.values().length`, но это неважно).

```java
MyEnum[] vals = {MyEnum.BAR, MyEnum.BAZ, MyEnum.ARG, MyEnum.ANT, MyEnum.FOO, MyEnum.QUX, MyEnum.ANT, MyEnum.FOO};
```

Почему при сортировке этого массива при помощи стандартного метода `Arrays.sort` получается результат:

```java
Arrays.sort(vals);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));

// [FOO, FOO, BAR, BAZ, QUX, ARG, ANT, ANT]
```

Как получить массив значений перечислений, отсортированный по алфавиту?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перечисления в Java представляют собой классы вида [`Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), которые в свою очередь реализуют интерфейс [`Comparable<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), то есть перечисления поддерживают *естественное упорядочивание (natural ordering)* благодаря реализации метода [`Enum::int compareTo(E o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo-E-).

В документации указывается, что естественный порядок, реализованный в данном методе -- это порядок, в котором были объявлены константы перечисления:

> `public final int compareTo(E o)`
> Compares this enum with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object. Enum constants are only comparable to other enum constants of the same enum type. **The natural order implemented by this method is the order in which the constants are declared.**

Фактически, для сравнения в естественном порядке используются значения `ordinal` (см. [пример реализации в Open JDK 8](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/8ff7d6ea0a9615fa4c5229afa5f0df8ad9c4f4f6/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Enum.java#L215-L222))

Соответственно, для сортировки массива перечислений *в алфавитном порядке* достаточно передать в перегруженный метод [`Arrays::sort(T[] arr, Comparator<? super T> cmp)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) компаратор по полю/методу [`Enum::name()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name--):

```java
Arrays.sort(vals, Comparator.comparing(MyEnum::name));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
// [ANT, ANT, ARG, BAR, BAZ, FOO, FOO, QUX]
```

Аналогичный компаратор следует использовать и при сортировке списков [`List::sort(Comparator<? super E> cmp)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-), потоков в Stream API [`Stream::sorted(Comparator<? super E> cmp)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) или для сортированных сетов / очередей приоритетов и т.п.